# Parse JSON or XML on bootup

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, json, xml

I'm compiling my own version of the linux kernel and I was wondering if there is any way to do parse a local XML or JSON file.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the kernel? Can't you do this in  an initialization script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsawk will probably do what you need: https://github.com/micha/jsawk

---

Edit: However I found [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) to work much better. Here is an example:
`curl 'http://twitter.com/users/username.json' | jshon -e "location"`
Outputs:
`"new hampshire"`

Comment: This is great! I was wondering if when the kernel fully loads it could print the parsed text. Could it do that?

Comment: If you use just run `jshon` without any options or switches, it "pretty prints" the entire json structure passed to jshon.